# What is the meaning of tbody > tr > td in CSS

Tags: css

Currently I'm trying to understand some CSS parts but couldn't able to understand them due to some notations.

i went through google but couldn't able to find something related to this

can someone **please explain the below CSS part?**

```
  tbody > tr > td {
    color: red;

  }
  
  tbody > tr > td:not(:empty) ~ td {
    
    color: green;

  }
  
  tbody > tr > td:empty,
  tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
    
    color: black !important;

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Set `color: red;` to the first `<td>` element.**

```
tbody > tr > td {
  color: red;
}
```

**2. Set `color: green;` to all `<td>` elements that are not empty.**

```
tbody > tr > td:not(:empty) ~ td {
  color: green;
}
```

**3. Set `color: black !important;` and `border: 1px solid black;` to the sixth `<td>` and all following `<td>` elements. Also, set `color: black !important;` and `border: 1px solid black;` to all empty `<td>` elements (see the fifth `<td>` element with a black border).**

```
tbody > tr > td:empty,
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
  color: black !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can create a snippet and see the effect.

```css
tbody > tr > td {
  color: red;
}

tbody > tr > td:not(:empty) ~ td {
  color: green;
}

tbody > tr > td:empty,
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
  color: black !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

That part applies to all `td` (table data) which are direct children of `tr` (table row) which are direct children of `tbody`, text color in these elements will be red.

```
tbody > tr > td {
  color: red;
}
```

That part applies to all `td` which are siblings of not empty `td` which are direct children of `tr` which are direct children of `tbody`, text color in these elements will be green. Documentation for CSS combinators: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

```
  tbody > tr > td:not(:empty) ~ td {
     color: green;
  }
```

That part applies to all empty `td` which are direct children of `tr` which are direct children of `tbody` (`tbody > tr > td:empty`). As well as to all `td` which are direct children of `tr` which are direct children of `tbody` except the first five (`tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6)`) and text color in these elements will be black. !important will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element.

```
  tbody > tr > td:empty,
  tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
    color: black !important;
  }
```

Useful :nth-child Recipes reference: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: Clearly explained !!!Thanks mate